# Speech to Text API for JavaScript

Tags: gratis, javascript, windows-8, api, speech-recognition

I'm looking for an API that can convert speech to text in real time. Language requirement is English. Is there any such free API available?

---

Edit:

I'm sorry to not have mentioned this earlier. The application I'm developing is a JavaScript-based Windows 8.1 app. So I need something that would work there. I hope it would support what most modern browsers can.

Answer (score 3):

For Google Chrome 25 and later you can use the [JavaScript Web Speech API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API):

- [demo](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html)
- [documentation](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html).

Some interesting points from the documentation:

> This specification was published by the Speech API Community Group. It
>   is **not a W3C Standard** nor is it on the W3C Standards Track
>
> The Web Speech API aims to enable web developers to provide, in a web
>   browser, speech-input and text-to-speech output **features that are
>   typically not available when using standard speech-recognition** or
>   screen-reader software. The API itself is agnostic of the underlying
>   speech recognition and synthesis implementation and can support both
>   server-based and client-based/embedded recognition and synthesis. The
>   API is designed to enable both brief (one-shot) speech input and
>   continuous speech input. Speech recognition results are provided to
>   the web page as a list of hypotheses, along with other relevant
>   information for each hypothesis.

I don't know which other browsers implement this API.